# How to run flutter projects from external disk?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to run flutter projects from an external disk, but so far I cannot do so both on android or IOS. It always comes up with these error on IOS simulator

```
 Running "flutter pub get" in myapp...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
/Volumes/dwika/myapp/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 37 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A here_sdk
      A shared_preferences
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_storage
      - image_picker

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `here_sdk` from `.symlinks/plugins/here_sdk/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "here_sdk":
      In Podfile:
        here_sdk (from `.symlinks/plugins/here_sdk/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `here_sdk (from `.symlinks/plugins/here_sdk/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12
```

If i put the folder inside my internal laptop ssd it works just fine, I want to run it from my external disk due to low storage in my laptop, anyway to do that? or I just have to accept reality that such thing is not possible? PS: I'm using Macbook Air M1 2020 on Mac OS Big Sur 11.6 .

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this issue still, the problem in my case was the apostrophe symbol in my drive's name. Karun's T7 Shield; remove the apostrophe, it might work.